# Import data into Hadoop with c#

Tags: c#, .net, hadoop, driver, hdfs

I have an existing application that imports data from a web site api into a MongoDB.  We have taken a sharp turn and now want to use Hadoop.  I have Cloudera VM working and now would like to change the application from inserting data from MongoDB into Hadoop.  Does anyone know of a driver like the MongoDB_CSharp driver that can be used for Hadoop/HDFS?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What format do you want to write it in?

Files on HDFS?  Look at the [HDFS REST API](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.0/webhdfs.html).

HBase?  Look at the [HBase Thrift API](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/ThriftApi).

Comment: I'm using Cloudera Manager and it doesn't support that functionality at this time.